# RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers the tabs doesn't show ios

Tags: ios

it's a library to make swipe-able tap-bar and move between the taps by swiping left and right

-> [library](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)

when i apply the code from app delegate it works perfectly , but when i do it using storyboard and in the RK Swipe Between View Controllers.m i add the view controllers in the view Controller Array when it loads the buttons don't show , even i print their titles and they exist and tried to make hidden = true but it still don't show , any help please

[my code](https://www.mediafire.com/?acssa5fjdx85qrc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Check this drop down options]

Change the option to Translucent Navigation Bar and make sure that there is a navigation bar in the storyboard.

[image]

Comment: it didn't change anything , please download my project and try to make it work

Comment: Oh I did this and showed me the navigation bar that's weird

Comment: Here is what i did 1. Download your file 2. Open it 3. Go to Storyboard 4. Change the Top Bar to Translucent Navigation Bar 5. Build and run 6. See the navigation bar    Please would you try again with the file you uploaded? Flow the exact steps on this comment.

Comment: you can upload here the project changes please , i tried exactly what you said and no buttons appear !

Comment: Good to hear that I was looking around for a way to upload the file :]